# Export cubic equation formulas to code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm writing code for the method to solve this cubic equation. I use python's math library.

```
(float)(-b+pow(pow(b,3)-27*pow(a,2)*d,1/3))/3*a;
 
(float)((math.sqrt(delta))/(3*a))*((pow(abs(k)+math.sqrt(pow(k,2)+1),1/3))+(pow(abs(k)-math.sqrt(pow(k,2)+1),1/3)))-(b/(3*a));
```

Below are pictures of 2 math formulas I need to solve:

[image: formula 1]

[image: formula 2]

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: `/3*a` at the end of your first line does not do what you think it does. Use parentheses!! Parentheses are important. Write `/ (3 * a)` instead.

Comment: It's mostly a matter of style, but personally I think `A**B` is easier to read than `pow(A, B)` (they are equivalent, as you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)).

Comment: The `(float)` things you put at the beginning of each line are not doing anything.

Comment: Note that your code will require `b`, `a`, `d`, `Delta` and `k` to be already-existing variables with already-given values. One way to get around that is to encapsulate your code into a function, with these four variables as arguments of the function. Another way to get around that is to use [the symbolic expression library `sympi`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

A few comments to begin with:

- `/3*a` at the end of your first line does not do what you think it does. Use parentheses!! Parentheses are important. Write `/ (3 * a)` instead.
- It's mostly a matter of style, but personally I think A**B is easier to read than pow(A, B) (they are equivalent, as you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)).
- Note that your code will require `b`, `a`, `d`, `Delta` and `k` to be already-existing variables with already-given values. One way to get around that is to encapsulate your code into a function, with these four variables as arguments of the function. Another way to get around that is to use [the symbolic expression library sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

With these comments in mind, here are two ways to rewrite your first expression and use it in python code. I will let you adapt the second expression yourself.

### First way: encapsulating in a function with arguments

```py
def expr1(a,b,d):
  numerator   = - b + (b**3 - 27*a*a*d)**(1/3)
  denominator = 3 * a
  return numerator / denominator

print(expr1(2,7,3))
# -0.7219330585463425
```

### Second way: using sympy

Sympy is a library for **symbolic calculus**. This means we can use it to define *symbols*, which are basically variables without a value, and then ask it to remember expressions that use these symbols. We are going to use the function `sympy.symbols` to define our symbols, and `expr.subs` to evaluate an expression `expr` by giving values to those symbols. I encourage you to read [sympy's documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html).

```py
import sympy

a, b, d = sympy.symbols('a b d')
numerator = - b + sympy.cbrt(b**3 - 27*a*a*d)
denominator = 3 * a
expr1 = numerator / denominator

print(expr1)
# (-b + (-27*a**2*d + b**3)**(1/3))/(3*a)

print( expr1.subs([(a,2), (b,7), (d,3)]) )
# -7/6 + 19**(1/3)/6

print( expr1.subs([(a,2), (b,7), (d,3)]).evalf() )
# -0.721933058546342
```

Comment: Can you help me with the 2nd recipe ;)

Comment: Good luck with the 2nd recipe ;)